# Is there a way to make Safari open a bookmark in a new tab automatically without a keystroke?

Tags: tabs, bookmarks, safari

The only way I can see to open the selected bookmark in a new tab is with a keystroke (control-click, or control-shift-click). I'd like to set Safari to automatically open a selected bookmark in a new tab. Other browsers seem to have this capability.

Comment: Are you trying to get new tab always open with a specific page (the bookmarked one) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mouse with a scroll wheel, you can push the scroll-wheel like a mouse button. This is a middle-click, and it will open a link in a new tab.

If you have at least a two-button mouse, you can right-click and choose to open a link in a new tab from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

hold cmd + double click the bookmark.